# Selenium Simple Chrome WebDriver: java compilation and execution problems

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit

I'm new to Selenium and I have little knowledge of the java compilation and run process, because I always compiled and executed with the help of the IDE.

## My problem

I'm trying to run a simple test with selenium (for learning purposes) to request "www.google.com" and assert that the title is the correct one.
My goal is to learn enough to use it on my work and reduce time doing manual testing on multiple browsers and OS.

My problem is that when I want to run the test from the command line it fails with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class`

I saw a lot of similar problems in SO but none of them helped me....

## What I have done

I did the following steps:

1. Follow this https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2 and start hub+node
2. Download the chromedriver and write this simple test class

   ```
   import junit.framework.TestCase;
   import org.junit.*;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;

   @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
   public class ChromeTest extends TestCase {

       private static ChromeDriverService service;
       private WebDriver driver;

       @BeforeClass
       public static void createAndStartService() {
           service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
                   .usingDriverExecutable(new File("tools/chromedriver"))
                   .usingAnyFreePort()
                   .build();
           try {
               service.start();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       @AfterClass
       public static void createAndStopService() {
               service.stop();
       }

       @Before
       public void createDriver() {
           driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(),
                   DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
       }

       @After
       public void quitDriver() {
               driver.quit();
       }

       @Test
       public void testTitleDevel() {
           driver.get("http://www.google.com");
           TestCase.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use maven and create a pom.xml

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
           <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
           <groupId>Test</groupId>
           <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                   <version>2.46.0</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>junit</groupId>
                   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                   <version>4.12</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                   <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                   <version>1.3</version>
                   <scope>compile</scope>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                   <version>12.0</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>

           <build>
       <sourceDirectory>/Users/user1/QAScripts/AmateurTest/src/</sourceDirectory>


               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>2.18.1</version>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </build>
       </project>
   ```

I have now the following directory structure:

Test
|--pom.xml
|--src
|------ChromeTest.java
|--tools
|------chromedriver
|------selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar

4. Run `mvn dependency:build-classpath`
5. Use that classpath to compile ChromeTest.java

`javac -cp "..HERE GOES CLASSPATH.." src/ChromeTest.java`

```
user1@tororrosso ~/T/src> ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  4 user1  staff   136 Jun 12 16:43 ./
drwxrwxrwx  8 user1  staff   272 Jun 12 16:41 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 user1  staff  2316 Jun 12 16:44 ChromeTest.class
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user1  staff  1372 Jun 12 16:43 ChromeTest.java*
```

6. Use the same classpath to run ChromeTest.class

`java -cp "..HERE GOES CLASSPATH.." org.junit.runner.JUnitCore src/ChromeTest`

But FAILS!!

```
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0,002
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [src/ChromeTest]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src/ChromeTest
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
        ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Tried with 
`java -cp "..HERE GOES CLASSPATH.." org.junit.runner.JUnitCore src/ChromeTest.class`

But it fails too

```
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0,002
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [src/ChromeTest.class]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src/ChromeTest.class
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
        ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

## Edit:

Tried too:

```
user1@tororrosso ~/T/> cd src
user1@tororrosso ~/T/src> javac -cp "....." ChromeTest.java
user1@tororrosso ~/T/src> java -cp "....." "ChromeTest"
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0,001
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [ChromeTest]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChromeTest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
        ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1

user1@tororrosso ~/T/src> java -cp "....." 'ChromeTest'
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0,001
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [ChromeTest]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ChromeTest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
        at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
        ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

## Edit2: My classpath

Maybe there is a problem with my classpath. But is what maven uses....

> /Users/user1/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/12.0/guava-12.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.5.2.Final/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/4.1.0/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/cssparser/cssparser/0.9.16/cssparser-0.9.16.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.17/htmlunit-2.17.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit-core-js/2.17/htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.22/nekohtml-1.9.22.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.4.1/httpclient-4.4.1.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.1/httpcore-4.4.1.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.4.1/httpmime-4.4.1.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.11.v20150529/jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.11.v20150529/jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.2.11.v20150529/websocket-api-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.2.11.v20150529/websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.2.11.v20150529/websocket-common-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.46.0/selenium-api-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/2.46.0/selenium-chrome-driver-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.46.0/selenium-firefox-driver-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver/2.46.0/selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-ie-driver/2.46.0/selenium-ie-driver-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-java/2.46.0/selenium-java-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-leg-rc/2.46.0/selenium-leg-rc-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/2.46.0/selenium-remote-driver-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-safari-driver/2.46.0/selenium-safari-driver-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.46.0/selenium-support-2.46.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/w3c/css/sac/1.3/sac-1.3.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/org/webbitserver/webbit/0.4.14/webbit-0.4.14.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.2/serializer-2.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xalan-2.7.2.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run class "src/ChromeTest" and I suspect your class file is not there.  Assuming your target folder is in your classpath, your java command-line should be 'java -cp "blah;foo;..." ChromeTest' (since you have no package).

Comment: Also, it appears you're trying to run Selenium via Selenium Grid.  To start learning Selenium, I'd suggest just running Selenium standalone and not use the grid hub.

Comment: compile via 'javac -cp "..." src/ChromeTest.java'

Comment: ok. Compiled, and ran like you said, but still the same error (see edit) :(

Comment: OMG. It was my classpath! I had to add ".:./src/:" to the beggining! Thank you!